# message.guild.members.cache.get() - возвращает undefined

Tags: discord, discord-api

Что-то подобное иговому боту. Информация о пользователях храниться в таблице users, куда записывается id пользователя и его баланс. Хочу сделать таблицу лидеров, а в нее вывести имя пользователя. Но

```
msg.guild.members.cache.get('userId')
```

Возвращает undefined

Answer (score 0):

Я смог решить эту проблему, надеюсь кому-то поможет это решение.

```js
message.guild.members.fetch('userId').then(result => {
   console.log(result) //result это и есть экземпляр класса GuildMember пользователя, которого вы запрашивали
})
```